# How can I merge (concatenate) two columns in an array/matrix?

Tags: arrays, perl, concatenation, multiple-columns

This is probably a pretty newb question, but….

In perl, I'm trying to read in a table (into an array) and combine the values of the first two columns.  So for an input file with:

```
1     7     ABC     DEF     GHI
2     8     ABC     DEF     GHI
3     1     ZYX     MNO     PLQ
```

I'd like to get out:

```
17     ABC     DEF     GHI
28     ABC     DEF     GHI
31     ZYX     MNO     PLQ
```

What's the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: you show us your code, we fix it. this is how SO works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so short, so I have to add extra text to the answer:

```
while(<>){ s/^(\S+)\s+/$1/; print}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of

```
Open file

#read file line by line

while input line
    remove trailing newline
    split line into an array
    make index 1 equal index 0 . 1
    remove first element from array
    print the elements of the array followed by \n #to STDOUT or file
```

Comment: Alternatively you can remove spaces with a substitution command without the global flag.